# How to find the last observation in the next 10 seconds comparing to the current row?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to find the last observation in the next 10 seconds comparing to current row, here is the example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data <- setDT(data.frame(price=c(4,5,3,1,0), 
                         datetime=c(as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:25"),
                                    as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:27"),
                                    as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:32"),
                                    as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:36"),
                                    as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:38"))))

#price   datetime
#1      4 2015/06/12 12:10:25
#2      5 2015/06/12 12:10:27
#3      3 2015/06/12 12:10:32
#4      1 2015/06/12 12:10:36
#5      0 2015/06/12 12:10:38
```

This is the desired output:

```
#price   datetime               next.price
#1      4 2015/06/12 12:10:25        3
#2      5 2015/06/12 12:10:27        1  
#3      3 2015/06/12 12:10:32        0
#4      1 2015/06/12 12:10:36        0
#5      0 2015/06/12 12:10:38        NA
```

Here is my code but it does not provide the desired output:

```
data.new <- data %>% rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(
  price=.$price,
  datetime= .$datetime,
  next.price = data[data$datetime <= .$datetime +10 ,"price", with=FALSE, mult="last"]
))
```

What do you generally do when you want to create a value for each row based on the subsequent rows? Questions such as: find the max/min in the subsequent rows, etc. Do you use `rowwise` from `dplyr`?

Comment: If your "datetime" is sorted, you could use `findInterval`; something like `price[findInterval(datetime + 10, datetime)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC this can be done using *rolling joins* as well:

```
# data.table v1.9.6
data[, next.price := data[.(datetime=datetime+10), price, roll=10-1, on="datetime"]]
#    price            datetime next.price
# 1:     4 2015-06-12 12:10:25          3
# 2:     5 2015-06-12 12:10:27          1
# 3:     3 2015-06-12 12:10:32          0
# 4:     1 2015-06-12 12:10:36          0
# 5:     0 2015-06-12 12:10:38         NA
```

This performs a *last observation carried forward (LOCF)* rolling join. For each value in `i = datetime+10`, it finds the matching row of the largest observation <= that value in `x = data`. We extract the corresponding `price` value and create a new column. `roll = 9` limits how far the values are carried forward to 9.

---

From the next version you wouldn't need the `datetime =`. It'd work with `.(datetime+10)` directly.